# I can't get the jquery .width() to work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got this HTML code:

```
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#">SPECS</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#">Specs 1</a>
        <a href="#">Specs 2</a>
        <a href="#">Specs 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#">GALLERY</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#">Gallery 1</a>
        <a href="#">Gallery 2</a>
        <a href="#">Gallery 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do, is that I don't want to specify the width of the .sub-menu in CSS, I want it to be dynamic, varying from the content of the div. I tried doing this with jQuery:

```
var width = $(".sub-menu").width();
$(".sub-menu").css("width", width);
```

But it's not working, it's giving the all the .sub-menu divs a width of 0px. I want maybe to use the .each function, so every .sub-menu would get its width and apply as css. I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all your anchor tags floated? or absolutely positioned? Is the div floated? This could be a css issue, therefore i suggest you include the relevant css.

Comment: it seems ok in this fiddle have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/3X6YJ/

Comment: Possible that the DOM is not yet loaded when you execute your javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
.sub-menu {display:inline-block}
```

This will make the menu take the width required by its content, no more.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `width()` returns a number. But the CSS rule requires `Npx`. Use this:

```
var width = $(".sub-menu").width() + "px";
$(".sub-menu").css("width", width);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sub-menu" ).each(function( index ) {
        width=$(this).width();
        $(this).css('width',width+'px');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should explain why you are doing this.

Comment: there are 2 div with class 'sub-menu', so i run a loop and find each div width and add it to corresponding div.

Comment: What I mean is, you shoud explain why you are using `.each` and how it is different from the OP's code.

Comment: .each find all div having class 'sub-menu'

Comment: You're missing the point I'm trying to make. Explain WHY the OP's code doesn't work, and explain HOW yours solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  var smWidth = $(".sub-menu").width();

  $(".sub-menu").css({ width: smWidth + 'px' });

});
```